# Destination Host Unreachable using 2 NIC Centos 7

Tags: centos, networking

I have 2 NIC on my PC on CentOS, they show as:

```
eth0: 192.168.0.174/23 local network
em1: 10.10.10.4/24 external network
```

When I try to make ping to 10.10.10.1 the iface that answered me is eth0.

```
[root@SFVOIP ~]# ping 10.10.10.1  
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.                         
From 192.168.0.174 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable  
From 192.168.0.174 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable  
From 192.168.0.174 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable  
  From 192.168.0.174 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable  
^C    
--- 10.10.10.1 ping statistics ---  
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5000ms
pipe 4
```

What could be my problem?

Comment: Please give additional informations and it should become more obvious: can you give the result of `ip -brief link ; ip -brief address ; ip route; ip route get 10.10.10.1` ?. If those won't help people to answer, you might also have to give iptables' (firewall) configuration: `iptables-save`. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/546328/edit) your question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was wrong routing; the connection/ping to 10.10.10.0/24 should not use the `eth0` network (which is 192.168.0.0/23) but go via `em1`.

The solution therefore was to delete the default route (including addresses 10.10.10.0/24) from the eth0 interface, and/or to add the 10-route to the `em1` as follows

```
ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/312682)

Comment: @perror It's a self-answer, so it looks ok to me.

Comment: So (since OP never added informations), I can only guess that there was this done `ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 dev eth0` (and with a metric option lower than on em1). And the "Destination Host Unreachable" appears initially after 3s when ARP resolutions fails to find the host on that side. Removing the wrong route solved the issue.